# Upload files to Digital Ocean Spaces with Next.js and AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, next.js, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I'm trying to make a files uploader (to Digital Ocean Spaces) using Next.js and AWS S3.

Everything works fine, but if I set my Digital Ocean Spaces env variables in the Next.js config file it fails. I have no idea why.
Here's my code:

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
import formidable from 'formidable-serverless';
import fs from 'fs';
import config from '../../config';

// export const config = {
//   api: {
//     bodyParser: false
//   }
// };

export default async (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3({
    endpoint: new aws.Endpoint('sfo3.digitaloceanspaces.com'),
    accessKeyId: config.NEXT_PUBLIC_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: config.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET_KEY,
    region: 'sfo3'
  });

  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500);

    const file = fs.readFileSync(files.file.path);

    s3.upload({
      Bucket: config.NEXT_PUBLIC_BUCKET,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Key: 'inserir-url',
      Body: file,
      ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
    })
      .send((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('err', err);
          return res.status(500);
        }
        return res.json({
          url: data.Location
        });
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.env` file and define your environment variables there.

Once done, simply replace `config.NEXT_PUBLIC_*` with `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_*`